# Plotting Multiple Series of Lines on the Same Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am attempting to graph battery cycling data similar to [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Chuang-Yu-2/publication/332227253/figure/fig4/AS:744333007396867@1554474226894/a-The-charge-discharge-curves-of-the-first-three-cycles-of-S-C-Li6PS5Br-Li6PS5Br-In-Li.ppm) . Each line is one cycle worth of datapoints and should be one line on the graph. At first the code I wrote simply saw the dataframe as a continuous variable, then I inserted a for loop that would graph 1 line for the 1 cycles worth of data, iterate to the next cycle 2 but currently it simply bugs and does not show any graph. Debug seems to show an issue once it loops past cycle 1. Each cycle does not have an equal amount of data points.

EDIT: I suspect now when looping the headers of the data is causing an issue. I think making a dictionary would solve this issue

```
df2 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\####\- ##### - ####\2-7_7.xlsx',\
                   sheet_name='record', usecols="A:N")
    
df2['Capacity(mAh)'] = df2['Capacity(mAh)'].apply(lambda x: x*1000) #A fix for unit error in the data

df2.set_index('Cycle ID',inplace = True) #Set the index to the Cycle number

for cycle in df2.index:
    chosen_cyclex = df2.loc[cycle, 'Capacity(mAh)']
    chosen_cycley = df2.loc[cycle,'Voltage(V)']
    plt.plot(chosen_cyclex.iloc[1],chosen_cycley.iloc[1])
    #print(chosen_cyclex[1],chosen_cycley[1])


plt.show()
```

Comment: The link is broken. Please post a screenshot of whatever you were trying to show, or something similar.

Comment: Edited with a new link from Google.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this method, where the equivalents were selected.

```
  for cycle in cyclearray:
        plt.plot(df2[df2.index == cycle]['Capacity(mAh)'],df2[df2.index == cycle]['Voltage(V)'],cycle
```

For other battery testers who show up here, if you need to 'cut' the voltages curves up, use

```
plt.xlim([xmin,xmax])
plt.ylim([ymin+0.1,ymax-0.1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an `ax` when plotting. Here are some examples:

```py
# reproducible (but unimaginative) setup
n = 100
cycles = 4

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': np.repeat(np.arange(cycles), n),
    'Capacity(mAh)': np.tile(np.arange(n), cycles),
    'Voltage(V)': (np.arange(n)**0.8 * np.linspace(5, 3, cycles)[:, None]).ravel(),
})
```

Example 1: using `groupby.plot`, then fiddle around to adjust labels

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df2.groupby('ID').plot(x='Capacity(mAh)', y='Voltage(V)', ax=ax)

# now customize the labels
lines, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
for ith, line in zip('1st 2nd 3rd 4th'.split(), lines):
    line.set_label(f'{ith} discharge')
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Example 2: `groupby` used as an iterator

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ld = {1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd'}
for cycle, g in df2.groupby('ID'):
    label = f'{cycle + 1}{ld.get(cycle + 1, "th")} discharge'
    g.plot(x='Capacity(mAh)', y='Voltage(V)', label=label, ax=ax)
```

Same plot as above.

Example 3: using `ax.plot` instead of `df.plot` or similar

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ld = {1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd'}
for cycle, g in df2.groupby('ID'):
    label = f'{cycle + 1}{ld.get(cycle + 1, "th")} discharge'
    ax.plot(g['Capacity(mAh)'], g['Voltage(V)'], label=label)
ax.legend()
```